# Disable programmatically noise suppression mic on iPhone 4/4S

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone-4

We have just launched an application on the AppStore very helpful and very friendly which appeals to a lot of people.
The application name is [BadSignal](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=510509736&mt=8), it simulates the loss of the network. When you're on a  phone call or during a conversation on Skype for example and you do not know how to get rid of your contact, launch the application and follow the instructions on the screen.

So much for the principle of operation.
Only problem, the iPhone 4 and 4S are equipped with a noise cancellation, which reduces  noise and crackling during a phone conversation that has the effect of suppressing the noises emitted by the application.

Do you know how to disable the second audio microphone during a session?
The iPhone SDK allows it to turn off microphone or even an external library such as OpenAL or portaudio?

Thx you in advance,
Steeven

Comment: I'm not sure Apple will let you mess with any phone-call related features --- it is a phone after all :). What do you mean by "the second audio microphone"?

Comment: The iphone 4/4S are equiped of a second microphone on the top of phone. This microphone cancel noise from main mic during a phone call. My app play sizzling and crackling noise for simulate bad signal reception and this mic cancel the noise effect !

Comment: If you have access to that mic's recording buffer, you can zero it out in a recording callback.